# Pandas read xml not working properly for single tag xml

Tags: python, pandas, xml-parsing

I am using the **pandas_read_xml** package for reading and processing xml files into a pandas dataframe. The package works absolutely fine for my purpose in the vast majority of cases. However, the dataframe output is kind of off when reading a url with just a single tag. Let me illustrate this with the following two examples.

```
# Import package
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
from pandas_read_xml import fully_flatten

# Example 1
url_1 = ‘https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1279392/000114554921008161/primary_doc.xml’
df_1 =  pdx.read_xml(url_1,['edgarSubmission', 'formData','invstOrSecs', 'invstOrSec'])
df_1 = pdx.fully_flatten(df_1)
```

The resulting df_1 contains 163 rows and 31 columns where each row corresponds to a unique security. This is in line with my desired result. However, the output is a little strange when I try to read a xml where there is just one occurrence of  the tag 'invstOrSec'.

```
# Example 2
url_2 = ‘https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1279394/000114554921008162/primary_doc.xml’
df_2  = pdx.read_xml(url_2,['edgarSubmission', 'formData','invstOrSecs', 'invstOrSec'])
df_2 = pdx.fully_flatten(df_2)
```

The resulting df_2 contains 6 rows and 19 columns. I can’t really make sense of why it contains 6 rows when it should really be one. I have observed that this behavior occurs in only those cases where there is just one occurrence of the tag 'invstOrSec'. Any help over this would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if my question isn't clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, in forthcoming Pandas 1.3, `read_xml` will allow you to migrate parsed nodes into data frames. However, because XML can have many dimensions beyond the 2D of rows by columns, as noted:

> This method is best designed to import shallow XML documents

Therefore, any nested elements are not immediately picked up as shown here with about 20 columns. Notice the required use of `namespaces` due to the default namespace in document.

**Pandas 1.3+**

```
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1279392/000114554921008161/primary_doc.xml"
df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath="//edgar:invstOrSec", 
                 namespaces={"edgar": "http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport"})

print(df)
#                                                   name  lei                                              title      cusip  ...  fairValLevel  securityLending  assetCat debtSec
# 0                                       Tastemade Inc.  NaN                                     Tastemade Inc.  999999999  ...           3.0              NaN      None     NaN
# 1    Regatta XV Funding Ltd., Subordinated Note, Pr...  NaN  Regatta XV Funding Ltd., Subordinated Note, Pr...  75888PAC7  ...           2.0              NaN  ABS-CBDO     NaN
# 2                Hired, Inc., Series C Preferred Stock  NaN              Hired, Inc., Series C Preferred Stock        NaN  ...           3.0              NaN        EP     NaN
# 3                      WESTVIEW CAPITAL PARTNERS II LP  NaN                    WESTVIEW CAPITAL PARTNERS II LP  999999999  ...           NaN              NaN      None     NaN
# 4                       VOYAGER CAPITAL FUND III, L.P.  NaN                     VOYAGER CAPITAL FUND III, L.P.  999999999  ...           NaN              NaN      None     NaN
..                                                 ...  ...                                                ...        ...  ...           ...              ...       ...     ...
# 158              ARCLIGHT ENERGY PARTNERS FUND V, L.P.  NaN              ARCLIGHT ENERGY PARTNERS FUND V, L.P.  999999999  ...           NaN              NaN      None     NaN
# 159                       ALLOY MERCHANT PARTNERS L.P.  NaN                       ALLOY MERCHANT PARTNERS L.P.  999999999  ...           NaN              NaN      None     NaN
# 160  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND V-F ...  NaN  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND V-F ...  999999999  ...           NaN              NaN      None     NaN
# 161                   ABRY ADVANCED SECURITIES FUND LP  NaN                   ABRY ADVANCED SECURITIES FUND LP  999999999  ...           NaN              NaN      None     NaN
# 162  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND IV-F...  NaN  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND IV-F...  999999999  ...           NaN              NaN      None     NaN

# [163 rows x 20 columns]


url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1279394/000114554921008162/primary_doc.xml"
df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath="//edgar:invstOrSec", 
                 namespaces={"edgar": "http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport"})

print(df)
#                                        name  lei                                     title      cusip  ...  invCountry  isRestrictedSec fairValLevel securityLending
# 0  Salient Private Access Master Fund, L.P.  NaN  Salient Private Access Master Fund, L.P.  999999999  ...          US                Y          NaN             NaN

# [1 rows x 18 columns]
```

Fortunately, `read_xml` supports XSLT (special-purpose language designed to transform XML documents) with default `lxml` parser. With XSLT, you can then flatten needed nodes for migration to retrieve the 32 columns.

```
xsl = """<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                       xmlns:edgar="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="edgar:invstOrSec">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|*/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
"""

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1279392/000114554921008161/primary_doc.xml"
df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath="//edgar:invstOrSec", namespaces={"edgar": "http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport"},
                 stylesheet=xsl)
print(df)
#                                                   name  lei                                              title      cusip  ...  annualizedRt  isDefault  areIntrstPmntsInArrs  isPaidKind
# 0                                       Tastemade Inc.  NaN                                     Tastemade Inc.  999999999  ...           NaN       None                  None        None
# 1    Regatta XV Funding Ltd., Subordinated Note, Pr...  NaN  Regatta XV Funding Ltd., Subordinated Note, Pr...  75888PAC7  ...        0.0624          N                     N           N
# 2                Hired, Inc., Series C Preferred Stock  NaN              Hired, Inc., Series C Preferred Stock        NaN  ...           NaN       None                  None        None
# 3                      WESTVIEW CAPITAL PARTNERS II LP  NaN                    WESTVIEW CAPITAL PARTNERS II LP  999999999  ...           NaN       None                  None        None
# 4                       VOYAGER CAPITAL FUND III, L.P.  NaN                     VOYAGER CAPITAL FUND III, L.P.  999999999  ...           NaN       None                  None        None
..                                                 ...  ...                                                ...        ...  ...           ...        ...                   ...         ...
# 158              ARCLIGHT ENERGY PARTNERS FUND V, L.P.  NaN              ARCLIGHT ENERGY PARTNERS FUND V, L.P.  999999999  ...           NaN       None                  None        None
# 159                       ALLOY MERCHANT PARTNERS L.P.  NaN                       ALLOY MERCHANT PARTNERS L.P.  999999999  ...           NaN       None                  None        None
# 160  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND V-F ...  NaN  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND V-F ...  999999999  ...           NaN       None                  None        None
# 161                   ABRY ADVANCED SECURITIES FUND LP  NaN                   ABRY ADVANCED SECURITIES FUND LP  999999999  ...           NaN       None                  None        None
# 162  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND IV-F...  NaN  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND IV-F...  999999999  ...           NaN       None                  None        None

# [163 rows x 32 columns]
```

**Pandas < 1.3**

To achieve same result via XPath approach requires more steps where you will have to handle URL request and XML parsing to data frame build. Specifically, create a list of dictionaries from transformed, parsed XML and pass into `DataFrame` constructor. Below uses same XSLT and XPath with namespace as above.

```
import lxml.etree as lx
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as rq

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1279392/000114554921008161/primary_doc.xml"

xsl = """<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                       xmlns:edgar="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="edgar:invstOrSec">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|*/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
"""

content = rq.urlopen(url)

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = lx.fromstring(content.read())
style = lx.fromstring(xsl)

# INITIALIZE AND TRANSFORM ORIGINAL DOC
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# RUN XPATH PARSING ON FLATTER XML
data = [{node.tag.split('}')[1]:node.text for node in inv.xpath("*")
        } for inv in result.xpath("//edgar:invstOrSec", 
                                 namespaces={"edgar": "http://www.sec.gov/edgar/nport"})]

# BIND DATA FOR DATA FRAME
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
#                                                   name  lei                                              title  ... isDefault areIntrstPmntsInArrs  isPaidKind
# 0                                       Tastemade Inc.  N/A                                     Tastemade Inc.  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN
# 1    Regatta XV Funding Ltd., Subordinated Note, Pr...  N/A  Regatta XV Funding Ltd., Subordinated Note, Pr...  ...         N                    N           N
# 2                Hired, Inc., Series C Preferred Stock  N/A              Hired, Inc., Series C Preferred Stock  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN
# 3                      WESTVIEW CAPITAL PARTNERS II LP  N/A                    WESTVIEW CAPITAL PARTNERS II LP  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN
# 4                       VOYAGER CAPITAL FUND III, L.P.  N/A                     VOYAGER CAPITAL FUND III, L.P.  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN
# ..                                                 ...  ...                                                ...  ...       ...                  ...         ...
# 158              ARCLIGHT ENERGY PARTNERS FUND V, L.P.  N/A              ARCLIGHT ENERGY PARTNERS FUND V, L.P.  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN
# 159                       ALLOY MERCHANT PARTNERS L.P.  N/A                       ALLOY MERCHANT PARTNERS L.P.  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN
# 160  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND V-F ...  N/A  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND V-F ...  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN
# 161                   ABRY ADVANCED SECURITIES FUND LP  N/A                   ABRY ADVANCED SECURITIES FUND LP  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN
# 162  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND IV-F...  N/A  ADVENT LATIN AMERICAN PRIVATE EQUITY FUND IV-F...  ...       NaN                  NaN         NaN

# [163 rows x 32 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. The Pandas 1.3 solution is fantastic. Please excuse my ignorance, but is it possible to install the dev version of Pandas 1.3. pip install pandas==1.3 can't find the version.

Comment: Good to hear coming from original author of the module! For dev version, you will need to `pip install` from the pandas git repo after cloning repo locally. See instructions on [home page of repo](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas). Note: not for novice Pythoners.

Comment: This is beautiful T^T

Answer (score 4):

First of all, thanks for the feedback! I wrote pandas-read-xml because pandas did not have a pd.read_xml() implementation. You (and the rest of us) will be pleased to know that there is a dev version of pandas read_xml which should be coming soon! (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html)

As for you current conundrum, this is a result (and one of my many dislikes towards) of the structure of XML. Unlike JSON, where single elements can be returned within a list, the XML structure just has one XML tag, which is interpreted as a single value rather than a list.

Essentially, if there is only one "row" tag, then the "column" tags is now treated as column tags... I'm not making much sense am I? Let me explain with your examples.

Here is how I suggest you use it:

```py
# Import package
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
from pandas_read_xml import fully_flatten

# Example 1
url_1 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1279392/000114554921008161/primary_doc.xml'
df_1 =  pdx.read_xml(url_1,['edgarSubmission', 'formData','invstOrSecs', 'invstOrSec']).pipe(fully_flatten)

# Example 2
url_2 = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1279394/000114554921008162/primary_doc.xml"
df_2  = pdx.read_xml(url_2,['edgarSubmission', 'formData', 'invstOrSecs'], transpose=True).pipe(fully_flatten)
df_2
```

What is the difference?

In Example 1, you already expect multiple  within  tag.
So, passing the root_tag_list=['edgarSubmission', 'formData','invstOrSecs', 'invstOrSec'] returns a list under the hood. The fully_flatten process would first explode the list into rows.

In Example 2, if you use the same root_tag_list, pandas is not reading in a list. Rather, it is reading in a dictionary that corresponds to the single row. In effect, it treats the tags intended as columns to be rows. Instead, I would pass one tag above it as the root tag, then transpose it, then fully_flatten.

Yes... I know... it is bit of a workaround. But... then again, I didn't create pandas-read-xml hoping to solve all the problems. It was always meant to be a interim solution until pandas natively supports reading XML (which it looks like it is coming soon).

Let me know how it goes!

EDIT:

Regarding how to make it so that the XML to pandas DataFrame conversion can switch depending on whether the XML has only one "row" tag or multiple, I have the following two options.

In the many row case, the DataFrame will result in a DataFrame with integer index (row numbers), whereas in the single row case, the DataFrame indices will be "Strings" that were meant to be columns. So one strategy would be to detect that and re-do accordingly. (you could probably avoid double downloading with a smarter approach)

```
# Import package
import pandas as pd
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
from pandas_read_xml import fully_flatten

# Example 3

dfs = []
url_components = ['1279392/000114554921008161', '1279394/000114554921008162']

for url_component in url_components:
    url = f'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/{url_component}/primary_doc.xml'
    temp = pdx.read_xml(url, ['edgarSubmission', 'formData', 'invstOrSecs'])
    if 0 not in temp.index:
        temp = pdx.read_xml(url, ['edgarSubmission', 'formData', 'invstOrSecs'], transpose=True)
    else:
        temp = pdx.read_xml(url, ['edgarSubmission', 'formData', 'invstOrSecs', 'invstOrSec'])
    dfs.append(temp)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).pipe(fully_flatten)

df
```

Another option is to use the underlying tools. There is no magic behind pandas_read_xml, it uses a package called xmltodict. Read the XML, convert to dicts, then convert to pandas, and then flatten. The only downside is that because the name of the tag "invstOrSec" is retained, they become prefixes for the column names. You should be able to remove those easily.

```
# Import package
import pandas as pd
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
import xmltodict
from pandas_read_xml import fully_flatten

# Example 4

url_components = ['1279392/000114554921008161', '1279394/000114554921008162']
xmldicts = []

for url_component in url_components:
    url = f'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/{url_component}/primary_doc.xml'
    xml = pdx.read_xml_from_url(url)
    xmldicts.append(xmltodict.parse(xml)['edgarSubmission']['formData']['invstOrSecs'])
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(xmldicts).pipe(fully_flatten)

df
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT:

So, I've updated the package (now version 0.2.0). Now the pandas_read_xml should treat the root tag as rows in the resulting pandas dataframe as default, so no need to distinguish XMLs that sometimes have single "row" and sometimes having multiple rows.

Should this be an issue in other cases, then there is a new argument `root_is_rows` that is True by default, but can be made False.

Comment: Just to add... there doesn't seem to be a "standard" way XMLs are constructed. You may need to tinker around with these things for each new data source you meet.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Your suggested approach delivers. However, it requires that I first identify URLs with single or multiple instances of 'invstOrSecs', before converting them into a data frame using either of the two approaches.  I have several thousand URLs to parse, and I am currently doing this in a for loop. Would you know if I can define an argument that enables me to filter out cases with single or multiple occurrences of 'invstOrSecs', so I can still parse them in a for loop.

Comment: Hey. So a couple of different options here. But before that, I am still not certain that there is a "clean" way of implementing something into the package itself, so the following workaround will have to do for now. Edit: I will reply as an answer rather than try to do it in comments.