# Read data from xml file and transform into python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I'm a very new user of Python/Pandas and I need to transform the data contained on the XML file on this link into a pandas dataframe:

https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/KEI

I have seen some tutorials on the internet and tried to execute them, using "xml.etree.ElementTree", "pandasdmx" and so on, including here on this website. But I didn't manage to make them work with this specific XML file.

When I open the XML file in Microsoft Excel I get the following table, which is precisely what I need, but in the form of Python/pandas code that transforms it into pandas dataframe so I don't have to extract it manually in Excel:
[opening XML file with Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdaLJ.png)

Here's the XML file: [Link for XML file on google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zpEVkXUgcFJw-rY5tjN3ZKZqXJoYmc3j/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: look at pandas "read_xml"

Comment: @balderman I tried pandas "read_xml", it does not return the data properly. Theres only 3 lines with "None" and "nan" on the dataframe.

Comment: 1). share the xml (make sure its valid) 2) share the desired DF

Comment: @balderman, forgive my lack of experience in this website, but I don't know what you mean. You mean share the xml file? I can't upload files to the post, but it is the one that is on the link: https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/KEI

Comment: @CSSWork: you should show us what you tried. Don't just say "But I didn't manage to make them work."

Comment: @CSSWork Try to provide a small xml that represent the actual xml.

Comment: @balderman I found the anwer I was looking for in other post. What I did was:

Comment: Follow the instructions from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66710039/pandas-read-xml-not-working-properly-for-single-tag-xml